# How to correct RSS XML file using AmpScript? Required for BuildRowsetFromXML to work

Tags: ampscript, xml

I'm trying to parse RSS feed to include it in the content of the email, I got the base script working, but I ran into trouble with some items descriptions that cause the BuildRowsetFromXML function to error out.

This is where the problem comes from:

```
<item>
  <title>Microsoft Azure – Virtuelle Konferenz: Praxiswissen: Von Experten für Experten</title>
  <description>&lt;p&gt;Aufgrund der großen Nachfrage veranstaltet Microsoft Deutschland nach zwei erfolgreichen Ausgaben vom 27. bis 29. Oktober 2015 die &lt;a href="http://www.somethingsomething.com 
" target="blank"&gt;3. Virtuelle Konferenz zur Cloud-Plattform von Microsoft&lt;/a&gt;. Täglich von 9 bis 16 Uhr geben unsere Experten in jeweils sechs Vorträgen technisches Know-how und Erfahrungen aus der Praxis rund um die Arbeit mit Microsoft Azure an Sie weiter. Die Themen erstrecken sich von allgemeinen Informationen über IT-Management in der Cloud bis hin zu für Entwickler relevanten Inhalten. &lt;/p&gt;
</description>
</item>
```

The link on third line is cut in half and continues on line 4. Is there any way to replace the line break (and possibly an empty space at the end of line 3) using AmpScript so that it is all properly on one line? Sadly, I don't have any option to touch the feed itself.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post your AMPScript.